# Java Script: New Date Format is not working for Nov and December

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change my date format

```
                var d = new Date();
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                var curr_Month = d.getMonth() +1;
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var todayDate =  var tDate =   ( curr_Month +"/"+curr_date +"/"+ curr_year);
```

This is working perfectly fine ,But for the month November it shows 10,instead of 11 and for the month of December it shows 11 instead of 12 ...for the rest of months it all fine ..

NOTE : This problem is only in mozilla and opera ,in internet explorer its working fine !

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: Your adding 1 to the month which is correct so that will all work fine. What are you using as Date() constructor arguments to *test* those dates, remember they need to be -1 from calendar dates.

Comment: @junaidp Your code works fine for me. Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: Seems to me that error is in the question not in date.

Comment: sorry, changed my question (edited) i want it in the format of mm/dd/yyy

Comment: What's the output? works perfectly here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function1

Comment: 10/1/2011   : if my date is November 1

Comment: `var d = new Date(2011, 10, 1)` (Simulate November 1), will output `"11/1/2011"` for me.  More information needed.  How did you simulate November 1?

Comment: Here is the ref to related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. **Edit** your original one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me, producing `11/23/2011` which is the current date in my timezone as of this answer, despite being that weird USA format :-)

This was tested in both Firefox 8 and IE 9 with the following HTML file:

```
<html><head></head><body><script language="javascript">
var d = new Date();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_Month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var todayDate =  (curr_Month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
alert (todayDate);
</script></body></html>
```

That last line of yours is not syntax I've seen before and, in fact, it stops the script from working at all. In IE9, you get:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error xyz.html, line 6 character 18
```

and Firefox 8 gives you:

```
[23:12:17.613] syntax error @ file:///C:/Users/Pax/Documents/xyz.html:6
```

Comment: working fine in Internet explorer  but this issue is appearing in mozilla and chrome

Answer (score 1):

You code should output `"11/23/2011"` without error.

For the `Date` element, `getMonth()` is 0-based. And Jan - Dec is displayed as 0-11.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> getMonth
>
> Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems perfectly fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2DSe/). What browser do you use (although I don't think it matters)?